# Java Android Studio restTemplate parse JSON

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a JSON from a URL - **WooCommerce API**.

The Problem is I cannot parse / output them in the app.

No errors, but it's showing up no data - just the Labels.

MainActivity.java:

```
    package at.copy_cat.app.rest;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        new HttpRequestTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            new HttpRequestTask().execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }


    private class HttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Greeting> {
        @Override
        protected Greeting doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final String url = "http://copy-cat.at/api/index.json";
                RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());



                /**Greeting greeting = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting[].class);**/
              Greeting greeting = restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting.class);

              /**  Greeting greeting = Arrays.asList(restTemplate.getForObject(url, Greeting[].class));**/
                RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();



                return greeting;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Greeting greeting) {
            TextView greetingIdText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id_value);
            TextView greetingContentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content_value);
            greetingIdText.setText(greeting.getId());
            greetingContentText.setText(greeting.getContent());
        }

    }

}
```

Greeting.java:

```
package at.copy_cat.app.rest;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
/**
 * Created by Michael on 17.10.2017.
 */



@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

public class Greeting {

    private String products;
    public String title;


    public String getId() {
        return this.products;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return this.title;

    }

}
```

With a simple JSON like this:
**{"id":161,"content":"Hello, World!"}**
It's working, but not with this generated JSON [here](http://copy-cat.at/api/api.php).

Yes its a .php file but I use in the Java code the .json with the same output like the PHP script...

The question is: how can I parse the information like products by ID etc.

Many thanks!

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
Now its looks like this

```
package at.copy_cat.app.rest;

import android.util.Log;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by Michael on 17.10.2017.
 */



@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

public class Greeting {


    // getters and setters
        public  List products;

        public String getContent(){
            String convertedToString = "" + products;
            /**String[] value_split = convertedToString.split(",");**/
            String[] value_split = convertedToString.split("\\,");


            try {

                JSONArray json = new JSONArray(products);


                for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);

                   /** Log.v("TEST23243235", "TESTOBJ" + e);**/
                    /**JSONArray people = e.getJSONArray("products");
                    int numOfPeople = e.getInt("images");**/
                    map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                    map.put("productid", "Product ID:" + e.getString("id"));
                    map.put("title", "Title: " +  e.getString("title"));
                    map.put("permalink", "Permalink: " +  e.getString("permalink"));
                    map.put("status", "Status: " +  e.getString("status"));
                    map.put("regular_price", "Regular Price: " +  e.getString("regular_price"));
                    map.put("price", "Price: " +  e.getString("price"));
                  //  map.put("description", "Description: " +  e.getString("description"));
                  //  map.put("categories", "Categories: " +  e.getString("categories"));
                   // map.put("images", "Images: " +  e.getString("images"));


                    Log.v("TEST23243235", "TESTOBJ" + map);
                    Log.v("TEST23243235", "TESTOBJ" +  json);
                    Log.v("TEST23243235", "TESTOBJI" +  i);
                    return map.toString();
                }



                // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList as class objects

                    /**JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = jObj.getString("id");

                    Log.d("TEST23243235", "TEST" + id);**/





            } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("TEST23243235", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
        // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.

        }
            return "";


        }

        public void setProducts(List products){

            this.products = products;
        }
        public class Model {
            private String title;

            //other fields

            //getters and setters
        }





    public String getId() {
        return "1";
    }

   /** public String getContent() {
     return this.convertedToString;

    }**/

}
```

Output in Logcat

```
TESTOBJ{price=Price: 30.00, regular_price=Regular Price: 0.00, title=Title: Camera DS, status=Status: publish, permalink=Permalink: http://copy-cat.at/produkt/camera-ds-2, id=0, productid=Product ID:590}

TESTOBJI0
```

So i can output now 1 product from the Json but not two or more....
What can i do to parse all products an not just one?

Yes code is not clean - sorry about that i learning... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `products` variable is private. It must has a  setter. Otherwise Jackson can not set value to it.

So, your json looks like that:

```
{
    "products": [
        {title and other fields}
     ]
}
```

So, your class should looks like that:

```
public class Products {
    private List<Model> products;
    // getters and setters 

    public static class Model {
        private String title;
        //other fields

        //getters and setters
    }
}
```

We use `Products` class as wrapper because json is wrapped in `products` field too.

Comment: Thanks but it is not the solution :(

Comment: @user2806316 I've just checked, .json version does not return json it redirects to html version. Are you sure about your URL?

Comment: Many many thanks i look at home and write you a Feedback :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the fact that in the json from the link, you get an object with an array of objects?

Comment: Yes and the question ist how i can parse that :)

Comment: What I always like to do is user the basic JSONObject and JSONArray class. I included links to the android developer page. Is that what you need?
JSONObject: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html
JSONArray: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

```
package at.copy_cat.app.rest;
import android.util.Log;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Created by Michael on 17.10.2017.
 */



@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

public class Greeting {


    // getters and setters
        public ArrayList products;

        public String getContent(){
            String convertedToString = "" + products;
            String[] value_split = convertedToString.split(",");

            Log.d("TEST23243235", "TEST" + products);

            return convertedToString;


        }

        public void setProducts(ArrayList products){

            this.products = products;
        }
        public class Model {
            private String title;

            //other fields

            //getters and setters
        }





    public String getId() {
        return "1";
    }

   /** public String getContent() {
     return this.convertedToString;

    }**/

}
```

Now i have the json output in the app and in the console.
The Problem now is - the output stops at ~1068 signs.

This is the output:

```
10-18 19:54:22.256 13706-13706/at.copy_cat.app.rest D/TEST23243235: TEST[{title=Camera DS, id=590, created_at=2014-08-18T19:58:28Z, updated_at=2017-09-05T12:48:07Z, type=variable, status=publish, downloadable=false, virtual=false, permalink=http://copy-cat.at/produkt/camera-ds-2, sku=451039, price=30.00, regular_price=0.00, sale_price=null, price_html=<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&euro;</span>30.00</span> &ndash; <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&euro;</span>44.00</span>, taxable=false, tax_status=taxable, tax_class=, managing_stock=true, stock_quantity=12, in_stock=true, backorders_allowed=false, backordered=false, sold_individually=false, purchaseable=true, featured=true, visible=true, catalog_visibility=visible, on_sale=true, product_url=, button_text=, weight=0.20, dimensions={length=35, width=45, height=13, unit=cm}, shipping_required=true, shipping_taxable=true, shipping_class=box1-he, shipping_class_id=68, description=<p>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a.</p>
                                                                    , short_description=<p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Donec ..., reviews_allowed=true, average_rating=0.00, rating_count=0, related_ids=[125, 126, 138, 118, 140], upsell_ids=[], cross_sell_ids=[], parent_id=0, categories=[Adapters, Batteries, Cables&amp;Adapters, Camcoder Tapes &amp; Discs, Cameras, Cases, Digital Cameras, Digital SLR, Discs], tags=[], images=[{id=399, created_at=2014-08-18T13:52:46Z, updated_at=2014-08-18T13:52:46Z, src=http://copy-cat.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/a21.jpg, title=a2, alt=, position=0}, {id=419, created_at=2014-08-18T13:53:09Z, updated_at=2014-08-18T13:53:09Z, src=http://copy-cat.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/a61.jpg, title=a6, alt=, position=1}, {id=414, created_at=2014-08-18T13:53:04Z, updated_at=2014-08-18T13:53:04Z, src=http://copy-cat.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/a51.jpg, title=a5, alt=, position=2}, {id=409, created_at=2014-08-18T13:52:58Z, updated_at=2014-08-18T13:52:58Z, src=http://copy-cat.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/a41.jpg, title=a4, alt=, position=3}, {id=404, created_at=2014-08-18T13:52:52Z, updated_at=2014-08-18T13:52:52Z, src=http://copy-cat.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/a31.jpg, title=a3, alt=, position=4}, {id=399, created_at=2014-08-18T13:52:46Z, updated_at=2014-08-18T13:52:46Z, src=http://copy-cat.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/a21.jpg, title=a2, alt=, position=5}, {id=394, created_at=2014-08-18T13:52:41Z, updated_at=2014-08-18T13:52:41Z, src=http://copy-cat.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/a11.jpg, title=a1, alt=, position=6}], featured_src=http://copy-cat.at/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/a21.jpg, attributes=[{name=colors, slug=colors, position=0, visible=true, variation=true, options=[Black, Green]}], downloads=[], download_limit=-1, download_expiry=-1, download_type=standard, purchase_note=, total_sales=19, variations=[{id=6892, created_at=2015-01-16T09:03:52Z, updated_at=2015-01-16T09:03:52Z, downloadable=false, virtual=false, permalink=http://copy-cat.at/produkt/camera-ds-2?attribute_pa_colors=black, sku=451039, price=30.00, regular_price=35.00, sale_price=30.00, taxable=false, tax_status=taxable, tax_class=, managing_stock=parent, stock_quantity=12, in_stock=true, backordered=false, purchaseable=true, visible=true, on_sale=true, weight=0.20, dimensions={length=35, width=45, height=13, unit=cm}, shipping_class=box1-he,
```

It stops @ shipping_class=box1-he, .

Output shout like this lenght http://copy-cat.at/api/index.json
Whats the Problem?

Thanks!

Comment: It cuts output because log cat has a limit of string length. Dont worry, your json is all right. Also, please don't post update us answer, please edit your post instead

Comment: Ok sorry for the new post :) Please look i have updated the first post with.